# How do I group documents together in Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have an `ArrayList<String> ids` which I can use to get documents inside a collection. For each ID in the array list of ids, I can do:

```
 DocumentReference doc = fstore.collection("Collection").document(id);
```

For a normal query you'd use:

```
 Query query = fstore.collection("Collection").whereEqualTo("field", value).orderBy("Field", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(5);
```

And then you can use `get()` to get the documents.

My question is how do I group these documents together so I can perform operations like `limit` `orderBy` and other methods available for collection queries.

Comment: What do you mean by "group these documents together"? Aren't you already ordering and limiting the results?

Comment: For each id in the array list of ids I can do 
`DocumentReference doc = fstore.collection("Collection").document(id);`
Now how do I add each document to a group and perform these operations

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution I can think of would be to save each operation you perform into a Task object and add each object to a List. As soon as the iteration completes, pass that list to [Tasks#whenAllSuccess(Collection> tasks)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks#whenAllSuccess(java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E%3E)) method, as you can see in the following lines of code:

```
List<Task<DocumentSnapshot>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
for (String id : ids) {
    Task<DocumentSnapshot> task = db.collection("Collection").document(id).get();
    tasks.add(task);
}
Tasks.whenAllSuccess(tasks).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Object>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<Object> list) {
        //Do what you need to do with your list
        for (Object object : list) {
            ModelClass mc = ((DocumentSnapshot) object).toObject(ModelClass.class);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I dont get it, how can I use `orderBy` and `limit` in this code?

Comment: In that case, what do you mean by "how do I add each document to a group"?

Comment: Meant something like getting only these specefic documents from the collection that im looking at

Comment: Would I have to use the ArrayList sorting methods? I have already implemeted this solution but I thought if there was something like this in firebase it'd work better

Comment: Yes, if you need to sort them, you can do that on the client.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: Yes I just added my models to an arrayLst and sorted them with them with `sort()`

Comment: Oh, good to hear that.

Comment: Can I help you with other information regarding this question?